# What do these commands do at the top of a class file?

Tags: documentclass-writing

I downloaded a class file and starts with the below code, would you be able to tell me what it does please? And would any of the commands become redundant whether XeLaTex/LuaLaTeX is used?

I have added comments to what I think certain lines may be doing but not too sure really, any additional info. would be great thanks!

```
\ProvidesClass{My Class}    % Name of the class
              [YYYY/MM/DD v1.0  LaTeX document class] % Additional info about the class
\def\baseclass{article} % Defining the command \baseclass as article
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}} % Pass all unknown options to the \baseclass (article class)
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass} % Passing a4paper to the baseclass (article class) 
\ProcessOptions\relax % Process the defined options above, and stop looking 
\LoadClass{\baseclass} % Load the defined baseclass

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\\\space}
```

Comment: So basically your question is about `\@checkoptions`? It's just checking whether the class has been loaded with some size option, and loads 10pt otherwise. The used engine is absolutely irrelevant here.

Comment: You can find some answers here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Packages .

Comment: @campa so the code between `\def\@checkoptions#1#2{}` is checking that a font size has been chosen, then choosing 10 pt with `\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}` if a size isn't chosen?

Comment: Yes, except for a typo (I meant 11pt, not 10).

Comment: @campa thanks! What about the last line? `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\\\space}`

Comment: Generally speaking you have to start with [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming?rq=1) and need to read a few books if you want to *write* some code...